# What does the "Assigned value is never used" warning mean?

Tags: java

```
unformatted = unformatted.replaceAll(seperator, "\n");
```

Netbeans gives me the warning:

> The assigned variable is never used

What does this mean?

Comment: just that. you assign the value, then never use that variable again elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you're not doing anything with that variable after you assigned a value to it. For example, you are not returning it, performing a calculation with it, passing it to a method, or anything else. It basically means that the variable has not been used after a value has been assigned to it.

Comment: Ah, I'm using the variable in a `while` statement right after it. Looks like it doesn't look there. Thanks!

Comment: How are you using it in the `while` statement?

Comment: what are you doing in this while loop? assigning a value to `unformatted` or reading it? NetBeans should respect all references.

Comment: Oh, I was doing something wrong! I created a `Scanner` with that `String` as the parameter, but I did that *before* that line of code, and used the scanner in the `while` statement. Now that I moved the creation of the `Scanner` to after that line, the warning disappeared.

Comment: It means the *value* is never used (not the variable as a whole).  You might initialise the variable to some value, but change the value in the variable before it is read, thus the initialisation is redundant.

Comment: A rather pedantic distinction; maybe you should let the compiler authors know.

Comment: @Vivin The difference is between being able to remove the variable from the code completely, and merely removing a redundant initialisation.  Hardly a pedantic difference.

Comment: @Jool the message literally says "The assigned variable is never used", which can happen if you assign a value to it as you initialize and then overwrite it (never having used the original value), and also if you don't use the subsequently overwritten variable.

Comment: @Vivin If the variable is entirely unused, Netbeans underlines it, meaning you can remove it safely from the code.  External utilities such as Findbugs will find them too.

Comment: @Jool I guess it depends on the IDE; in IntelliJ it underlines it in both cases (redundant initialized value *and* unused variable), and I assume Findbugs will probably find both cases as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a standerd rule which your IDE keeps checking just to help you avoid unwanted variable declarations maintainig clean code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not used the variable anywayere after assigning value to it

Answer (score 1):

```
The assigned variable is never used
```

The line itself self explaining.

Its because`unformatted`  is initialized, but is never used, making the  initialization unnecessary.

**It helps you out to make your code cleaner and to get rid doff from unnecessary memory waste**.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that your `unformatted` variable get never read.